# Typescript interface extend from Partial<T> creates diamond problem for extended interfaces wanting to also extend T

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend a Partial interface for a type, but this prevents me from requiring the fields that have already been provided in any interface that extends the original type.

Example:

```
interface Text {
    text: string;
}

interface ButtonStyles extends Partial<Text> {
    isBold?: false;
}

// is this a variant of the diamond problem?
interface Button extends ButtonStyles, Text {}
```

This produces `error TS2320: Interface 'Button' cannot simultaneously extend types 'ButtonStyles' and 'Text'1`. However, I am able to override the interface without extending `Text` by defining `Button` like this:

```
interface Button extends ButtonStyles {
    text: string;
}
```

What I really want is to have `ButtonStyles` not require a `text` property, but to allow it - while also force `Button` implementations to have a `text` property. Is there a more proper way to extract the properties as optional for the base interface while letting them be for the extended interface? Is there a name for this problem?

Comment: So what's wrong with `interface Button extends ButtonStyles { text: string; }` ?

Comment: This is a pretty trivialized example. Let's pretend `Text` has several properties I want and I want to make it really easy to change the definition of what makes a `Text` and pass those changes along to all of my buttons and other extended types easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapped types [allow](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers) to add or remove optional (`?`) modifier from the props. So you could add a utility that makes specified keys required:

```
interface Text {
    text: string;
}

interface ButtonStyles extends Partial<Text> {
    isBold?: boolean;
}

type WithRequired<T, TKeys extends keyof T> = T & { [P in TKeys]-?: T[P] };

type Button = WithRequired<ButtonStyles, keyof Text>;

const button: Button = { } // Error - Property 'text' is missing ...
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Text1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ButtonStyles%20extends%20Partial%3CText1%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isBold%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20WithRequired%3CT%2C%20TKeys%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20T%20%26%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20TKeys%5D-%3F%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Button%20%3D%20WithRequired%3CButtonStyles%2C%20keyof%20Text1%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20button%3A%20Button%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20%2F%2F%20Error%20-%20Property%20'text'%20is%20missing%20...)

Answer (score 0):

**The code below would be one of the proper ways to go!**

There is no problem to override field type since your requirement on that way. "Button" is another type collects from ButtonStyles however differs from it too.

```
interface Text {
    text: string;
}

interface ButtonStyles extends Partial<Text> {
    isBold?: false;
}

//Overeriding the optional text field
interface Button extends ButtonStyles {
    text: string
}
```